Change background for navigation dialog (jetpack compose)
I use a navigation dialog where I want to change the begraund color. I almost succeeded, but there are some paddings at the top and bottom of the screen that I can't do anything about... Maybe someone has encountered a similar problem and was able to solve it, I would be very grateful for any help
So i use dialog for navigation
dialog(
        Screens.Auth.route,
        dialogProperties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
    ) {
        AuthAssembly(
            authService = dependencies.authService,
            onCancel = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        )
    }

And on the screen i use surface
Surface(
    color = Color(0xFF1C1F3C).copy(alpha = 0.8f),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
   // content...
}



What version of Compose are you using? Because going into the status bar area wasn't possible until this fix was added.

"androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"
"androidx.compose.material3:material3"

I think you need to grab the modifier from the parent composable
Surface should be like this
    Surface(
    color = Color(0xFF1C1F3C).copy(alpha = 0.8f),
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize() //this from the parent compose fun
) {
   // content...
}


This surface is the bottom view in the hierarchy on this screen, so I have nowhere to pass the modifier from
